# If $f_n(x):=x+1/n$ and $f(x)=x$ for $x \in \mathbb{R},\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$ to $f$, but $\{(f_n)^2\}$ does not.

Tags: real-analysis

I am supposed to show that if $f_n(x):=x + \frac{1}{n}$ and $f(x):=x$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$ to $f$, but the sequence $\{(f_n)^2\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ does not converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$.

I made the first part, given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N=\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ such that $n>N$ implies $|f_n(x)-f(x)|= \frac{1}{n}< \frac{1}{N}=\epsilon$.

But for the second part, with the negation of the definition, I am stuck. Can you help me?

Comment: Did you simply compute $f_n^2(x)-f^2(x)$? Why not?

Comment: start defining the pointwise convergence of $\{f_n(x)^2\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ for each $x\in\Bbb R$

Answer (score 1):

Uniform convergence means for a sequence of $f_n: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ to a $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$
\begin{align}
\forall \epsilon > 0 \;\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}  \;\forall x\in\mathbb{R} \; \forall n\geq n_0 :|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon
\end{align}
which equivalent to
\begin{align}
\forall \epsilon > 0 \;\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}   : \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon \text{ if } n\geq n_0
\end{align}
I mentioned this only because in many comments you can read something about $\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f_n(x)-f(x)|$.

Anyway the negation of the first formular is
\begin{align}
\exists \epsilon > 0 \;\forall n_0 \in \mathbb{N}  \;\exists x\in\mathbb{R} \;\exists n\geq n_0: |f_n(x)-f(x)|\geq\epsilon
\end{align}
So you have to find a $\epsilon>0$ (in your case $\epsilon=1$ will do it) such that no matter how big you choose $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there will always be a $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\geq\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: for a given $n$, compute
$$
\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} |f_n(x)^2 - f(x)^2|.
$$

Comment: Since $\{f_n(x)^2\}$ converges pointwise to $f(x)^2$, so if it has to converge uniformly somewhere, it must converge uniformly to $f(x)^2$, now use the above hint to get a contradiction.